# If statement throws unexpected end of file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Whenever I run this script the find part executes but the if statement causes this error:

```
./list_datasheets.csh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

this is the script:

```
find $1  -type d | while read -r dir
    do
    for f in ${dir}/*
    do
        echo ${f} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
    done
done
if ($2 == "both") then 
    echo 'bye'
else
    echo 'hi'
endif
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try replacing the last line (`endif`) with `fi`, which is the correct token to close an `if` statement.

Also, replace `($2 == "both")` with the correct `[ $2 == "both" ]`.

Oh, and then, actually the `if` should be written as:

```
   if [ "$2" = "both" ]; then
      echo 'bye'
   else
      echo 'hi'
   fi
```

Note the quotes around `$2`, the spaces after `[` and before `]` and the `;` before the `then`.

Comment: That solved that problem now i get the error line 8: both:command not found

Answer (score 2):

You need to end the `if` block with a `fi` and not `endif`.

I guess you got confused with the `#endif` way of closing the `#if` block in C and C++.